# Pandas groupby. Grouping covid19 cases by continents

Tags: pandas

File
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cx9kasx83qmsi33/AABfOzVgzBuQe2ORU_t65J4Ta?dl=0

What I have done.

Here is the code I used
import pands as pd

## Read the csv file and set the file as 'covid'

covid.groupby('continent').TotalCases() it generates
KeyError: 'continent'

Comment: covid.groupby('continent') is an iterator which returns a continent in each iteration, try doing : for continent, group in covid.groupby('continent'): print(group.TotalCases)

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. It generated an error. KEYWORD ERROR: 'continent'. Maybe it is the formatting but I encoded it in UTC-8. Maybe it is the code

Comment: your csv file doesn't seem to have the column continent...